# SQLException "No value specified for parameter 3"

Tags: java, mysql

I am not receiving this error with the edit button but I am receiving it when I press the save button. It seems like all my parameters are there but maybe I am missing something. I've combed over the code for the save button over and over again but can't seem to understand whats wrong.What I want it to do is overwrite the data for a specific record according to the user input for part number and due date.

```
 PreparedStatement myquery3;             
 String InsertQuery3 = " UPDATE TABLE AllRecords SET DueDate = ? WHERE WorkOrderID = ?"
                        + "values(?,?)";                    
 myquery3 = conn.prepareStatement(InsertQuery3);
 myquery3.setString(1, duedate);
 myquery3.setString(2, workorder);
 myquery3.execute();
```

Comment: You're committing the class Swing sin: all your code in one class.  You've got console I/O, Swing, and database interactions and mingled together in one method.  You'll get further faster if you start decomposing your problem into separate classes and unit testing them.

Comment: in `InsertQuery3 ` there is 4 expected parameters, but you only set two

Comment: `InsertQuery2` and `InsertQuery3` look like very weird insert queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the problem:

```
String InsertQuery2 = "UPDATE TABLE Sample SET PartNumber = ? WHERE WorkOrderID = ?"
                            + "values(?,?)";                    
                myquery2 = conn.prepareStatement(InsertQuery2);
                myquery2.setString(1, partnumber);
                myquery2.setString(2, workorder);
                myquery2.execute();
```

you define 4 placeholder but only two are set.

you did the same mistake for `InsertQuery3`.

as a side note. the correct update sql looks like: `update table fubar set col1 = ? where id = ?`

`values` is used for `insert`

Comment: Well, not the same query but you were faster ^^ Please not that the next one have the same problem. `InsertQuery3`. And there is 4 placeholder

Comment: The values clause isn't even valid SQL.    That should be part of an INSERT, not UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. I am not home currently to work on this issue but i do understand exactly what I did wrong.